# Add element to a bibtexfile in Python

Tags: python, bibtex

I have created a script which scrapes many pdfs for abstract and keywords. I also have a collection of bibtex-files in which I want to place the texts I've extracted. What I'm looking for is a way of adding elements to the bibtex files.

I have written a short parser:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding: utf-8

import os
from pybtex.database.input import bibtex

dir_path = "nime_archive/nime/bibtex/"
num_texts = 0

class Bibfile:
  def __init__(self,bibs):
    self.bibs = bibs
    for a in self.bibs.entries.keys():
      num_text += 1
       print bibs.entries[a].fields['title']
       #Need to implement a way of getting just the nime-identificator
       try:
         print bibs.entries[a].fields['url']
       except:
         print "couldn't find URL for text: %s " % a


    print "creating new bibfile"



bibfiles = []
parser = bibtex.Parser()


for infile in os.listdir(dir_path):
    if infile.endswith(".bib"):
      print infile
      bibfiles = Bibfile(parser.parse_file(dir_path+infile))
```

My question is if there is possible to use Pybtex to add elements into the existing bibtex-files (or create a copy) so I can merge my extractions with what is already available. If this is not possible in Pybtex, what other bibtex parser can I use?

Comment: You need to indent your code properly. In Python this is **not optional**. `num_text += 1` is not indented correctly; besides that, try to keep a 4-space indentation throughout the whole code and do not change it (as you did in the last few lines)

Comment: Thanks for the syntax tip. I'm using TextMate, and try to keep consistent syntax, but when I copy, move around and change things it sometimes get a bit inconsistent, especially since I can't visually see whether it's tabs or spaces, or there is no cue if the block is three or four indentations deep. Is there a good way of cleaning and make the code more correct in this manner?

Comment: There's the Python style guide, a.k.a. as [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Preferably, read it all, but at least read the part on [indentation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) (very short summary: always indent with multiples of four spaces; never use tabs. A good text editor automatically converts this).

Answer (score 1):

I've never used pybtex, but from a quick glance, you can add entries. Since `self.bibs.entries` appears to be a `dict`, you can come up with a unique key, and add more entries to it. Example:

```
key = "some_unique_string"
new_entry = Entry('article',
        fields={
            'language': u'english',
            'title': u'Predicting the Diffusion Coefficient in Supercritical Fluids',
            'journal': u'Ind. Eng. Chem. Res.',
            'volume': u'36',
            'year': u'1997',
            'pages': u'888-895',
        },
        persons={'author': [Person(u'Liu, Hongquin'), Person(u'Ruckenstein, Eli')]},
    )
self.bibs.entries[key] = new_entry
```

(caveat: untested)

If you wonder where I got this example form: have a look in the `tests/` subdirectory of the source of pybtex. I got the above code example mainly from `tests/database_test/data.py`. Tests can be a good source of documentation if the actual documentation is lacking.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this looks like something that I've been looking for. I'm still stuck at a problem. I already have the bibliographic data, but I want to merge them together with abstract and keywords. Is there any Python construct I can use to access an element and then add the required part?

Comment: Here is the code I try to execute: https://github.com/olovholm/NIME/blob/master/bibtexparser.py The error that I am presented with states: Error: 'Entry' object does not support item assignment (Lines 48 and 49)

Comment: The dir(bibtex.Entry) = ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'add_person', 'get_crossref']

Comment: What version of pybtex are you using? I installed the version from the repository (as per the instructions on the webpage) and I don't get your error.

Comment: I'm using the version: pybtex- 0.16 Error is:
http://www.nime.org/proceedings/2001/nime2001_015.pdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bibtexparser.py", line 95, in <module>
    bibfiles = Bibfile(parser.parse_file(dir_path+infile),infile)
  File "bibtexparser.py", line 65, in __init__
    self.bibs.entries[a]['abstract'] = results[res[0]]['abstract']
TypeError: 'Entry' object does not support item assignment
1x-193-157-251-80:NIME ola$

Comment: @olovholm Since I only tested with a dummy bib file: is there any chance you can make the troublesome bib file available so I can test this properly?

Answer (score 0):

.data.add_entry(key, entry) works for me. Here I used an entry manually created (taken from Evert's example) but you can copy an existing entry from another bib that you're also parsing.

```
   from pybtex.database.input.bibtex import Parser
   from pybtex.core import Entry, Person

   key = "some_unique_string"

   new_entry = Entry('article',
           fields={
               'language': u'english',
               'title': u'Predicting the Diffusion Coefficient in Supercritical Fluids',
               'journal': u'Ind. Eng. Chem. Res.',
               'volume': u'36',
               'year': u'1997',
               'pages': u'888-895',
           },
    persons={'author': [Person(u'Liu, Hongquin'), Person(u'Ruckenstein, Eli')]},
       )

   newbib_parser = Parser()
   newbib_parser.data.add_entry(key, new_entry)
   print newbib_parser.data
```